# How do I put 5 text colors in 5 rows using for loop in multiplication table php?

Tags: php

thank you in advance for helping me. I am stuck with this problem. I should put different colors of text per row but I only know alternating 2 colors per row. [This should be the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w02vm.png)

```
<?php
    $color1 = "#32CD32";
    $color2 = "#FF0000";
    $color3 = "#5e0087";
    $color4 = "#FFA500";
    $color5 = "#00008b";
    $color = NULL;
      echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
        for ($row=1; $row <= 5; $row++) { 
        echo "<tr> \n";
        $color == $color1 ? $color = $color2: $color = $color1; 
        for ($col=1; $col <= 4; $col++) { 
        $num = $col * $row;
        echo "<td style = 'color:$color'>&nbsp$num&nbsp</td> \n";
        }
          echo "</tr>";
    }
      echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Put them into an array, an use $array[$row] on the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can create dynamic variables in php by creating the string (like "color1" and then putting `$$` before it.

```
    $color1 = "#32CD32";
    $color2 = "#FF0000";
    $color3 = "#5e0087";
    $color4 = "#FFA500";
    $color5 = "#00008b";
    $color = NULL;
      echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
        for ($row=1; $row <= 5; $row++) { 
        echo "<tr> \n";
        $color = "color".$row; 
        $color = $$color;
        for ($col=1; $col <= 4; $col++) { 
        $num = $col * $row;
        echo "<td style = 'color:$color'>&nbsp$num&nbsp</td> \n";
        }
          echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Here's another option, put the colors in an array

```
 $colors = ["#32CD32", "#FF0000", "#5e0087", "#FFA500", "#00008b"];
```

then just access the array with the $row #

```
$color = $colors[$row -1];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should avoid using individual variables to store related data.  By assigning these colors as elements in an array, you afford yourself the ability to loop over the collection of values without the use of "variable variables" (when your script seems to *need* variable variables, then it is time to rethink your script).

   ```
   $colors = [
       1 => "#32CD32",
       2 => "#FF0000",
       3 => "#5E0087",
       4 => "#FFA500",
       5 => "#00008B"
   ];
   ```
2. You should avoid writing inline styles as much as possible.  In truth, I'd recommend that you completely color your rows of text using pure css.  However, I get the impression that this is just an exercise in writing dynamic code.

   ```
   <style>
       table {
           border-collapse: collapse;
           width: 1%;
       }
       td {
           border: solid 1px black;
           padding: 8px;
       }
   </style>
   ```
3. I find myself paying an increasing amount of attention to generating clean well-tabbed source code (in addition to producing clean rendered html).  To assist in satisfying my quest, I'll use template strings with `printf()` and `vsprintf()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FO7WQ))

```
<?php
$tr = <<<HTML
    <tr style="color: %s;">%s
    </tr>

HTML;
$tds = str_repeat("\n        " . '<td>%s</td>', 4);
?>
<table>
<?php
    foreach ($colors as $key => $color) {
        printf(
            $tr,
            $color,
            vsprintf(
                $tds,
                range($key, $key * 4, $key)
            )
        );
    }
?>
</table>
```

Unrendered Output:

```
<table>
    <tr style="color: #32CD32;">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color: #FF0000;">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color: #5E0087;">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color: #FFA500;">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color: #00008B;">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Rendered HTML]

---

Using pure CSS is the more professional technique for styling.  Once you move the css to an external stylesheet, your php script will be very short and easy to manage.

Code with the same output: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YWRDX))

```
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 1%;
    }
    tr:nth-child(1) { color: #32CD32; }
    tr:nth-child(2) { color: #FF0000; }
    tr:nth-child(3) { color: #5E0087; }
    tr:nth-child(4) { color: #FFA500; }
    tr:nth-child(5) { color: #00008B; }
    td {
        border: solid 1px black;
        padding: 8px;
    }
</style>
<?php
$tr = <<<HTML
    <tr>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
    </tr>

HTML;
?>
<table>
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; ++$i) {
        vprintf(
            $tr,
            range($i, $i * 4, $i)
        );
    }
?>
</table>
```